# Creating a Alamofire Response for a test

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsurl, alamofire

I am using Alamofire in my iOS application for API calls.  I am trying to stub this data out in the tests, I have tried Mockingjay and OHHTTPStubs but neither work, so I am now trying to stub the response that I receive back.

I need to create a Response with dummy data which I can pass to my other methods. Here is the initializer for the Response object in Alamofire:

```
public init(request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, data: NSData?, result: Result<Value, Error>)
```

However I cannot work out how create this object, as I cannot create a Result.  Here is some of the result class from Alamofire:

```
public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType> {
    case Success(Value)
    case Failure(Error)

    /// Returns `true` if the result is a success, `false` otherwise.
    public var isSuccess: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Success:
            return true
        case .Failure:
            return false
        }
    }

    /// Returns `true` if the result is a failure, `false` otherwise.
    public var isFailure: Bool {
        return !isSuccess
    }

    /// Returns the associated value if the result is a success, `nil` otherwise.
    public var value: Value? {
        switch self {
        case .Success(let value):
            return value
        case .Failure:
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Returns the associated error value if the result is a failure, `nil` otherwise.
    public var error: Error? {
        switch self {
        case .Success:
            return nil
        case .Failure(let error):
            return error
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to work out how to pass a result to the response object with a value in it, to represent an API response.

I think I'm getting confused about enums, and how they can have variables in them also.

Can anyone help me build a response?

Thanks.

**ANSWERED**

Thanks for the answer...  Here is how you create the whole response with a json response

```
let london : NSDictionary = ["name" : "london", "latitude" : 23.00, "longitude" : 0.0, "id" : "london_gb"]
                let paris : NSDictionary = ["name" : "paris", "latitude" : 30.00, "longitude" : -1.0, "id" : "paris_fr"]
                let locations = NSArray(array: [london, paris])
                let result = Result<AnyObject, NSError>.Success(locations)

                var response = Response(request: NSURLRequest(), response: NSHTTPURLResponse(), data: NSData(), result: result)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see an example below:

```
let result = Result<String, NSError>.Success("Hello")

result.isSuccess // prints true
result.value // prints "Hello"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much!  This has worked perfectly..  Will update my question with the full response

Answer (score 2):

Base one the answer of @66o but update to Swift 4 / Alamofire 4

```
import Alamofire
...

let result = Result<Any>.success("Hello")
let dataResponse = DataResponse(request: nil, response: nil, data: nil, result: result)
```